# KnockoutJS UI not binding on first load

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

This is my first stab at knockoutjs. Code is below. The getJSON call is working. I can see the response in Fiddler and I have validated with JSLint (ie the JSON response). I can see the array being populated in Chrome console, but for some reason the UI is not updating with the data fetch from the server. Can anyone see what I've missed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Section(data) {

    this.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Selected = ko.observable(data.Selected);
}

function SectionsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ViewName = ko.observable();
    self.Sections = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Initial load

    $.getJSON("/Service/view/GetJSON?viewID=@ViewBag.ViewID", 
                      function (allData) {
        self.ViewName = allData.ViewName;
        var mappedSections = $.map(allData.Sections, 
                                               function (item) { 
                                                   return new Section(item) });
        self.Sections = mappedSections;
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new SectionsViewModel());

</script>

<h2>Edit View</h2>

<table class="dataEntryTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Selected</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Sections">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ID()"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name()"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected()" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Update with `self.ViewName(newValue)` instead of `self.ViewName = newValue`

Comment: This has been marked down for not showing any research, is unclear or not helpful. Research effort consisted of going through all of the tutorials on the knockoutjs site, and examining every part of the message chain with VS debugger, Chrome console, JSLint and Fiddler. The question is incredibly clear and will be most helpful to anyone who has followed the same route .. sheesh what do some people need :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update ko with the observables function:

```
self.ViewName(allData.ViewName);
var mappedSections = $.map(allData.Sections, function (item) { 
                                                 return new Section(item) });
self.Sections(mappedSections);
```

Also in your binding, remove the parenthesis (you are binding to the value of the observable instead of the observable itself):

```
<td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected" /></td>
```

Finally, you need to call `ko.applyBindings(new SectionsViewModel());` ***after*** your html has rendered to bind the loaded html to your view model (either put the script after the html, or use an event to call it on document ready).

Comment: No difference I'm afraid :(

Comment: @SimonRigby There was another problem, I updated. Hope I got it all this time :)

Comment: Still the same .. the parens were there when I was trying anything earlier to get it to work .. have removed them .. same thing. V odd

Comment: Is your script tag before your html or is it just here?

Comment: Yup its before .. script tag open and closed then markup .. It's an MVC4 view to be precise but the layout is exactly as it appears in the question.

Comment: ah .. here's a thought .. does the script have to be in the head?

Comment: I think you need to put `ko.applyBindings(new SectionsViewModel());` after your html has loaded, since it will apply the viewmodel to the html

Comment: ok yes that's done it .. odd that point was never made in the otherwise excellent tutorials on the knockout site. If you update your answer with this I will accept it when I can. FYI I added a second script block below the HTML with the ko.applyBindings statement in it, although I could probably move all the script code to the bottom. Many thanks I've spent far too long staring at this ;)

Comment: Many Thanks .. now I can move on :)

Comment: @SimonRigby Your edit was [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5148483), but I updated my answer to include what you wanted to say